# How do I convert Dax Date Serial to date

Tags: excel, dax

I need to be able to transform the value of column that contains 0 and date Serial Number to display date when a date is required and 0 not the date 12/1/1899.

If zero value  then 0 else the shortdate(date serial).

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another column with an IF statement that evaluates the date column and only returns the date if the column is not zero.

```
=if([Date]=0,BLANK(),[Date])
```

[image]

Or, if you use Power Query, add a step to the query to replace zero with null.

Comment: what would be the proper syntax?  if termed date = date serial then return date(termedDate) else 0?

Comment: I added the formula and a screenshot